# php foreach html output - newbie

Tags: php, html, foreach, logic

sorry for the very stupid question.
It seems to be more of a logical problem than a programming one, but whatever.

So i have this nice array that I want to output in html and I wnt to split it in groups of three elements.

```
<DIV>
   product1
   product2
   product3
</DIV>
<DIV>
  product4
</DIV>
```

this is my code

```
 $counter = 0;

        foreach ($prods as $prod) {
            if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
                $htm_l .= '<div data-count="' . $counter . '">';
            }

            $htm_l .= '<br> PROD' . $counter;
            $counter++;

            if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
                $htm_l .= '</div>';
            }
        }
```

Of course it produces wrong results like:

```
<div data-count="0">
    <br> PROD0
    <br> PROD1
    <br> PROD2
</div>
<div data-count="3">
    <br> PROD3
```

Missing a closing div.
What is a clean way to achieve my result? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `$counter=3` it will increment `1` by using `$counter++` so now `$counter=4`

and your condition for check

```
 if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
       $htm_l .= '</div>';
 }
```

its wrong and no `</div>` assign so after `forloop` end you will set `$counter=0` and then check

```
if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
       $htm_l .= '</div>';
}
```

so it will work

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$htm_l="";
foreach ($prods as $prod){
    if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
        $htm_l .= '<div data-count="' . $counter . '">';
    }

    $htm_l .= '<br> PROD' . $counter;
    $counter++;

    if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
        $htm_l .= '</div>';
    }
}
$counter=0;
if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
    $htm_l .= '</div>';
}
echo $htm_l;
```

Comment: this works fine, I don't know if it's the cleanest way, but it's a good way

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution move `$counter++;` after condition. Your complete code will be:

```
 $counter = 0;
$htm_l = "";

foreach ($prods as $prod) {
    if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
        $htm_l .= '<div data-count="' . $counter . '">';
    }

    $htm_l .= '<br> PROD' . $counter;
    if($counter == 0 || ($counter % 3) == 0) {
        $htm_l .= '</div>';
    }
    $counter++;


}

echo $htm_l;
```

Comment: In this case after the first cycle since counter is 0 you close immediately the /div  <div data-count="0">
        <br> PROD0
        <br>
    </div>. then it works fine, we should check if it's the really first cycle but I think it's not a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
$html = '';
$new_array = array_chunk($prods, 3);
$i = 0;
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {
    $html .= '<div data-count="'.$i.'">';
        foreach ($value as $ele) {
            $html .= '<br>'.$ele;
            $i++;
        }
    $html .= '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at array_chunk(), which chunks an array into arrays with X elements: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$prods = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4'];
foreach (array_chunk($prods, 3) as $chunk) {
    echo '<div>' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($chunk as $product) {
        echo '<br>' . $product  . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</div>'  . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Probably works too, but since in my case $products is an object wich is foreachable, but not strictly an array it doesn't work, since the first argument of array_chunk must be an array. Of course we can fill an array first or do other things.